# Slow LOOP in PLSQL

Tags: performance, loops, select, plsql, insert

This query is too slow can you help me to speed this up? The query inserts into MB_TXDV_042014 data using the 'select where' node like a filter for each value on t.num_sequencial. I need to extract data from some tables to MB_TXDV_042014 but i don't want to use too much memory for the processes.

Thanks

```
How do i speed this up guys?

DECLARE
    counter NUMBER;

BEGIN

FOR counter IN 1..1000000
LOOP
insert into MB_TXDV_042014
    (cod_unidade, num_sequencial, num_taxa, quant, modulo, num_episodio, data, designacao, valor_acto)
select sh.cod_unidade, t.num_sequencial,t.num_taxa,1 quant, 'CON' modulo,c.con_episodio episodio, c.dta_realizacao data, 'Consulta Externa' des_adm, nvl(t.valor_acto, 0) valor
from ide_taxas t,con_registadas c, sys_hospital sh, ide_controle ic
where c.num_taxa = t.num_taxa
   and t.tipo_taxa = '2'
   and t.taxa='S'
   and t.num_episodio is not null
   and c.dta_realizacao >= to_date('01-01-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')
   and c.dta_realizacao < to_date('10-04-2014','dd-mm-yyyy')
   and t.num_sequencial = ic.num_sequencial(+)
   and t.num_sequencial = counter
   and ic.dta_obito is null;
   COMMIT;
END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: Rule number 1 of asking for SQL performance help: explain what the query is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that you need a loop.  Why can't you just do this:

```
insert into MB_TXDV_042014
    (cod_unidade, num_sequencial, num_taxa, quant, modulo, 
     num_episodio, data, designacao, valor_acto
    )
    select sh.cod_unidade, t.num_sequencial,t.num_taxa,1 quant, 'CON' modulo,
           c.con_episodio episodio, c.dta_realizacao data, 'Consulta Externa' des_adm, 
           nvl(t.valor_acto, 0) valor
        from ide_taxas t,con_registadas c, sys_hospital sh, ide_controle ic
        where c.num_taxa = t.num_taxa
            and t.tipo_taxa = '2'
            and t.taxa='S'
            and t.num_episodio is not null
            and c.dta_realizacao >= to_date('01-01-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')
            and c.dta_realizacao < to_date('10-04-2014','dd-mm-yyyy')
            and t.num_sequencial = ic.num_sequencial(+)
            and t.num_sequencial <= 1000000
            and ic.dta_obito is null;
```

Comment: the problem is that i need a commit for each record, thats why i use the loop

Comment: "and t.num_sequencial <= 1000000" to include the last one

Comment: @user3523130, if you need to do 1,000,000 transactions with commits, it is going to be slow.  But why do you need to do that?  You should really update your question to explain exactly what you are doing and why you have this requirement.

Comment: I need to extract data from some tables to MB_TXDV_042014 but i don't want to use too much memory for the processes, because in could exist too much data. thats qhy i thought a commit will keep the memory fresh

Comment: @user3523130, 1,000,000 rows is a trivial amount in any modern RDBMS.  You really don't need to worry about it.  Also, databases are designed to handle large operations in an efficient way.  By inserting one row at a time, you are bypassing their inbuilt optimization and making things much less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The elephant in the query is commit at each row. This can't be "fast".

dan1111 is the best answer, in the sense it can't be faster. (there is no engine switch and data copy between SQL and PL/SQL).

Your alternatives are:

1. Bulk collect
2. `dbms_parallel_execute`

In your case, I would investigate `dbms_parallel_execute` with a chunk size of 1.

here is a bulk collect version, with no guarantee:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE rec IS RECORD(
    cod_unidade    ide_controle%TYPE,
    num_sequencial ide_taxas.num_sequencial%TYPE,
    num_taxa       ide_taxas%TYPE,
    quant          NUMBER,
    modulo         VARCHAR2,
    episodio       con_registadas.con_episodio%TYPE,
    dta_realizacao con_registadas.dta_realizacao%TYPE,
    des_adm        VARCHAR2,
    valor          ide_taxas.valor_actor%TYPE);

  TYPE col IS TABLE OF rec;
  lines col;

BEGIN

  SELECT sh.cod_unidade,
         t.num_sequencial,
         t.num_taxa,
         1 quant,
         'CON' modulo,
         c.con_episodio episodio,
         c.dta_realizacao data,
         'Consulta Externa' des_adm,
         NVL(t.valor_acto, 0) valor BULK COLLECT
    INTO lines
    FROM ide_taxas t, con_registadas c, sys_hospital sh, ide_controle ic
   WHERE c.num_taxa = t.num_taxa
     AND t.tipo_taxa = '2'
     AND t.taxa = 'S'
     AND t.num_episodio IS NOT NULL
     AND c.dta_realizacao >= TO_DATE('01-01-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
     AND c.dta_realizacao < TO_DATE('10-04-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
     AND t.num_sequencial = ic.num_sequencial(+)
     AND t.num_sequencial <= 1000000
     AND ic.dta_obito IS NULL;
  FORALL 1 IN 1 .. lines.count
  INSERT INTO mb_txdv_042014
     (cod_unidade, num_sequencial, num_taxa, quant, modulo, num_episodio, data, designacao, valor_acto)
   VALUES  lines(i);

  /* -- normal way.
  FORALL 1 IN 1 .. lines.count
    INSERT INTO mb_txdv_042014
      (cod_unidade, num_sequencial, num_taxa, quant, modulo, num_episodio, data, designacao, valor_acto)
    VALUES  lines(i);
  */


  FOR i IN 1 .. lines.count LOOP
    INSERT INTO mb_txdv_042014
      (cod_unidade, num_sequencial, num_taxa, quant, modulo, num_episodio, data, designacao, valor_acto)
    VALUES lines(i);
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;


END;
```

at least you execute the select once, not a million time, and more efficiently (less parses will be done, and buffers will be used).

Comment: i was searching for this method but theres and error on the line: TYPE col IS TABLE OF rec      expecting . ( @ % not null range index

Comment: Well, varchar2 type should have a length, like varchar2(30).